# Link variables (one web page to others)

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a bunch of web pages. If i put a variable ,`x`, in a web page and `y` in another web page how can i add them (`x + y`) and find my result in the 2nd web page (the page where `y` is).

Comment: Add more information

Answer (score 3):

you should use the `import/export` statement in the variable you want to import.
So if you have in the first web:

```
<script>
var x = 1
</script>
```

and the second web its like:

```
<script>
var y = 2
</script>
```

You should have in web one:

```
<script type=module>
export var x = 1
</script>
```

And the second web:

```
<script>
import x from '/firstweb.html';
var y = 2;
var z = x + y;
</script>
```

Anyway if you show your code maybe we can help you a little bit more.